# Javascript - hide div 1 sec before live stream on video ends

Tags: javascript, html, video, timeout, intervals

I have this in page:

```
<video src="blob://some-live-stream" autoplay></video>
<div id="hideMePlease"> hide 1 sec before video ends</div>
```

I would like to hide the div 1 sec before the video ends, how can i do?

*N.B: i can't know video duration, it's a live stream , and the video autostops so i have no way to stop it myself.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you state, you cannot know the length of the video because it's streaming, it will be *impossible* (relativistic time travel notwithstanding) for you to schedule an event one second before it finishes.

However, I would at least first *try* to use the duration property of the video, it may be that metadata is made available as part of the stream early on. If it is, you can use that to schedule the hiding of your `div`.

> As an aside, if you visit the page http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html, you'll find that the duration is set correctly as soon as you start playing the video, despite the fact it seems to be streaming from either an MP4, OGG or WEBM file). So it's at least *possible,* though it may depend on the data stream itself (whether the metadata comes before or after the actual video data).

If the data is *not* available (I think you get `Inf` for the duration in that case), then you're just going to have to hide the `div` at the earliest possible time after that.

That would presumably be when it finishes (fires the `onended` event).

So, in short, if you can *get* the duration (or periodically get the time remaining which might be better), use that. Otherwise fall back to hiding it at the end and start hassling w3c to provide the functionality you want in HTML6.

Comment: could be great to hear more opinions about this, but at the end i think it's impossible as you correctly said :)